# setState in not calling after event triggered in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, react

I have a little portfolio dApp that mints NFTs.

After a successful mint, I want the UI to display the tokenId of the minted NFT.

I'm minting successfully and the event is being triggered - {tokenId} logs, but setNFTzMinted is never called.

```
const askContractToMintNft = async () => {
  try {
    const { ethereum } = window;

    if (ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      // 3 params we need to connect to our contract
      const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, myEpicNft.abi, signer);

      console.log("Going to pop wallet now to pay gas...")
      let nftTxn = await connectedContract.makeAnEpicNFT();
      setIsLoading(true);

      console.log("Mining...please wait.")
      await nftTxn.wait();
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(`Mined, see transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
      await connectedContract.on("NewEpicNFTMinted", (from, tokenId) => {
        console.log({tokenId});
        setNFTzMinted(tokenId.toNumber());
      });
      console.log({NFTzMinted})
    } else {
      console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on? I could always run my view function to get the tokenId, but it seems like an extra step.

I feel like the callback function on connectedContract should work.

Thanks!
JVj

Comment: This is fundamentally a question about React hooks. This question should be moved to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and it should include more details about the code.

Comment: Would need to see a bit more of your code to know for sure. Might be that your ```console.log({NFTzMinted})``` is getting called before the state has updated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I called await nftTxn.wait() before connectContract.on(...).

The event emitted before nftTxn.wait() finished.

Thanks for the help will post more code next time to start!

The code below works as expected.

```
const askContractToMintNft = async () => {
  try {
    const { ethereum } = window;

    if (ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      // 3 params we need to connect to our contract
      const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, myEpicNft.abi, signer);

      console.log("Going to pop wallet now to pay gas...")
      let nftTxn = await connectedContract.makeAnEpicNFT();
      setIsLoading(true);
      connectedContract.on("NewEpicNFTMinted", (from, tokenId) => {
        console.log('NewEpicNFTMinted');
        console.log({tokenId});
        setNFTzMinted(tokenId.toNumber());          
      });
      console.log("Mining...please wait.")
      await nftTxn.wait();
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(`Mined, see transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
      
      
      console.log({NFTzMinted})
    } else {
      console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

}